# Function gives list, I need DataFrame so I can concatenate

Tags: python, pandas

I started off pulling all files in the folder and concatenating them, this one works:

```
warranty_list = []
warranty_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(qms, '*.csv'))
for file_ in warranty_files:
df = pd.read_csv(file_,index_col=None, header=0)
warranty_list.append(df)
warranty = pd.concat(warranty_list)
```

Then I had to write a function so I would only grab certain files and concatenate them, but this one is not working. I do not get an error but the last line is not being used, so I am not concatenating the files.

```
def get_warranty(years=5):
    warranty_list = [] #list for glob.glob()
    current_year = datetime.datetime.today().year #current year
    last_n_years = [str(current_year-i) for i in range(0,years+1)]
    for year in last_n_years:
        warranty = glob.glob(os.path.join(qms, "Warranty Detail%s.csv" % year)) 
        if warranty:
            for file_ in warranty:
                df = pd.read_csv(file_,index_col=None, header=0)
                warranty_list.append(df)
            warranty_df = pd.concat(warranty_list)
```

The last line isn't working presumably because the pd.concat() is getting a list as an input and it won't do anything with that. O don't understand why it worked in the first set of code and not this one.

I don't know how to change the function to get a data frame or how to change what I get at the end into a data frame.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I do not understand your question. What, **exactly** isn't working? Presumably, you are getting some error? You should share the error message including the stack trace. Provide a [mcve]

Comment: It would be good to debug a little your function. E.g., checking the type (`print(type(df))`, e.g.) and contents of your variables throughout. It is unlikely that, if both `pd.concat` uses receive *similar* lists with the same type of elements, one of them would not produce a sensible return value.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use directly append because it do same thing as concat

So basically you start with an empty dataframe

```
warranty_df = pd.Dataframe()
```

And then append the the others dataframe to this while reading the file

So your function should remain the same but you need to delete the following line

```
warranty_df = pd.concat(warranty_list)
```

And after the loop, you return the warranty_df!

```
def get_warranty(years=5):
    warranty_df = pd.Dataframe()
    current_year = datetime.datetime.today().year #current year
    last_n_years = [str(current_year-i) for i in range(0,years+1)]
    for year in last_n_years:
        warranty = glob.glob(os.path.join(qms, "Warranty Detail%s.csv" % year))
        if warranty:
            for file_ in warranty:
                df = pd.read_csv(file_,index_col=None, header=0)
                waranty_df = warranty_df.append(df)

    return warranty_df
```

Comment: One shouldn't copy/paste formatting errors of the OP into an answer.

Comment: Okay, so it has taken me some time to get back to this, but now it appears that the function isn't doing anything. I can run it without errors but I get nothing out of it, any idea why that may be?